# AngularJS 1.4, bootstrap multi level Accordion sample

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to build a menu something like as below but I am not finding an appropriate sample utilising AngularJS 1.4, bootstrap & accordion. 
Accordion is a must. Please advise.

```
menu1
menu2
  submenu2.1
  submenu2.2
     sub-submenu2.2.1
     sub-submenu2.2.2
menu3
```

I have added the code below.  Style sheet is Bootstrap.css. Also some custom stylesheet used in project. Accordion menu elements should have different colours at each level of menu. Also the one selected should be displayed in different color. When we hover over elements it should display different color.
As per the below implementation I have 2 main level elements in menu. The first element is displaying proper accordion behaviour. Second element is always open.
No stylesheet is getting applied to either of the menu elements. Please advise.

**HTML:**

```
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="menuTree">
      <uib-accordion-group is-open="firstMenuItemStatus.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="firstMenuItemStatus.isFirstDisabled">
        <uib-accordion-heading ng-if="c.pDtos">
            {{c.name}}
        </uib-accordion-heading>
        <div ng-repeat="p in c.pDtos" ng-include="'smenuTree'"></div>
      </uib-accordion-group>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="smenuTree">
      <uib-accordion-group>
        <uib-accordion-heading>
          {{p.name}}
        </uib-accordion-heading>
        <div ng-show="p.aDtos" ng-repeat="a in p.aDtos">
          <a ui-sref="crhDetail({ crhId : a.crhId})">{{a.name}}</a>
        </div>
      </uib-accordion-group>
  </script>
  <div class="menuSec" ng-controller="menuCtrl">
    <uib-accordion close-others="true">
      <div ng-repeat="c in menuTreeSet" ng-include="'menuTree'" >
      </div>
    </uib-accordion>    
  </div>
```

**Custom CSS:**

```
.menuSec {top: 80px;left: 0;right: 0;bottom: 0;}
.menuSec>ul {position: absolute;background:#2166b3;width:100%;}
.menuSec>ul>li, .secondLevelList>li, .thirdLevelList>li{position: relative;float: right;display:block;list-style: none;width: 100%;height: 40px;line-height: 44px;text-align: right;font-size: 12px;padding-right: 14px;box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #3A76C4;cursor: pointer;}
.secondLevelList, .thirdLevelList{width:220px;}
.secondLevelList>li, .thirdLevelList>li{width:220px;height:30px;line-height: 32px;float: right;list-style: none;}
.selected{height:auto !important;background:#135aa9;border-left: 3px solid #000033;border-bottom:none;box-shadow:none !important;}
.secondLevelList>.selected{background:#004388;}
.menuText{position:absolute;text-align:right;right:47px;}
.menuSec ul li:hover {background: #135aa9;border-left: 3px solid #000033;}
.menuSec ul li .fa {margin-left: 14px;line-height: 40px;}
.secondLevelList, .thirdLevelList{position:relative !important;float:right;display:block;border-top:1px solid #000033;}
.secondLevelList{margin-right:-14px;}
.thirdLevelList{margin-right:-24px;}
.secondLevelList>li{background:#0a4d99;border-bottom:1px solid #2a66a9;padding-right:24px;}
.selected>.secondLevelList>li:hover{background:#004388 !important;}
.secondLevelList>li:hover{background:#003b78;}
.thirdLevelList>li{background:#004388;border-bottom:1px solid #18589f;padding-right:34px;}
.thirdLevelList>li:hover{background:#003871 !important;}
.thirdLevelList>.selected, .thirdLevelList>.selected:hover{padding-right:10px;background-image:url(../images/NowWeAt.png) !important;background-position:right !important;background-repeat:no-repeat !important;}
.menuSecCT{width:80px;overflow:hidden;}
.menuSecCT .menuText{display:none;}
.menuSec ul li{padding-right:34px;}
.secondLevelList, .thirdLevelList{display:none;}}
```

Comment: get rid of bootstrap.js and use angular-ui-bootstrap which has a collapse directive

Comment: I am using this sample but its only for one level. Please advise how to proceed for nested levels.  http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of multi-level (3 levels) UI Bootstrap accordion. You have to adapt to your needs.

This example is based on ng-include:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="menuTree">
      <uib-accordion-group>
        <uib-accordion-heading ng-if="menu.listChilds">
          <a href="{{menu.href}}">{{menu.label}}</a>
        </uib-accordion-heading>
        <div ng-repeat="submenu in menu.listChilds" ng-include="'smenuTree'"></div>
      </uib-accordion-group>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="smenuTree">
      <uib-accordion-group>
        <uib-accordion-heading >
          <a href="{{submenu.href}}">{{submenu.label}}</a>
        </uib-accordion-heading>
        <div ng-show="submenu.listChilds" ng-repeat="item in submenu.listChilds">
          <a href="{{item.href}}">{{item.label}}</a>
        </div>
      </uib-accordion-group>
  </script>

  <div ng-controller="MenuController">
    <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
      <div ng-repeat="menu in items" ng-include="'menuTree'"></div>
    </uib-accordion>
  </div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ERURCsdvjhts1ujkYTrz?p=preview

Comment: I am still stuck with this . Somehow the bootstrap css does not apply to this accordion. I tried using ng-class but still unable to color the elements at different level . Please help.

Comment: I have updated my non-working code in the original question.

Comment: Please refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve in order to share a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example". If you try to apply a CSS class and do not share its definition (i.e. the stylesheet), how someone could help you?

Comment: I have posted the css of menu that I want to apply. Please advise how to proceed further.

Comment: http://www.menucool.com/vertical/accordion-menu   this link contains the exact type of menu I need however I cannot use this code for 2 reasons. (1) When I using angular tags along with this menu  the menu does not display . (2) This is licensed code and will work only in Dev / Local .

Comment: Sorry, the CSS code you shared does not apply to Bootstrap accordion: the reason is very simple: there are no `<ul>` or `<li>` elements...

Comment: Do you have a sampe CSS i could apply to the uib-accordion?

Comment: Does this mean we cannot apply css to accordion ?

Comment: No you can apply CSS rules to uib-accordion but you have to know how they work and apply them correctly. Check which Html elements are involved in this accordion and define appropriate styles for the right selectors...

Comment: I am using the uib-accordion as in the original question. I observed that in the bootstrap.css in my project panel-class style element was missing . I have added it now and I am able to add style to accordion. However one thing I observe is the secondlevel shows from under the first level though its collapsed. Is there a way I could hide the second level when the accordion is collapsed at first level.

Comment: I need some help with this please. I am using the above uib-accordion however the last element of the accordion is not responding to clicks & all its sub elements are shown by default.  Looks like something is wrong with the looping logic for accordion. Kindly review the same.

Comment: I have created plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/H72AL47rHnf8WHNUFPhk?p=preview    It works in plnkr, but when I use this code in my app the Catalog28 element is completely open. Please advise.

Comment: I also want the functionality when one accordion opens the others at those level should close. Please advise.

Comment: Your Plunker works, so probably you did errors integrating the Accordion in your main project. For other questions please read Angular UI bootstrap.